# Приложение

Tags: приложение

Коли парень ты румяный..
Что в этом предложении будет являться приложением: слово ты, парень или его здесь вовсе нет?

Comment: @Екатерина Сорина, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Здесь нет приложения.

ты - подлежащее, парень - сказуемое, румяный - определение. Здесь инверсия. В прямом порядке было бы: коли ты румяный парень...

Answer (score 0):

Приложение - это определение, выраженное существительным, которое дает другое название, характеризующее предмет. В вашем случае определение выражено прилагательным, поэтому не является приложением.

Comment: А могут ли 2 части речи: местоимение и существительное, стоящие в таком виде, быть подлежащим?Я думала, что-то из этого является приложением.

Comment: парень ты румяный - СИС.

Answer (score 0):

И приложение как-то обособляется: запятыми или тире, может писаться через дефис: ученики- старшеклассники.